# How do I increase the height of a sliding glass door lock?

Tags: doors, carpentry, metal

I recently installed a dog door panel for my sliding patio glass door. The way the dog door was made I had to install it centered in the patio door channel vs flush with the sliding glass door.  This has created a problem that doesn't allow me to install the hinge that will lock the door closed. There is a good 1/2 inch difference in height.

I'd like to make a shim or something to raise the hinge placed on the dog panel to be flush with the sliding glass door. I'll need to be able to drill through the object to anchor it into the dog panel. I've never created something like this and I'd like to hear if anyone has some suggestions on how to proceed.

[image]

Comment: I don't really get what I am looking at. Where is the dog door in all of this?

Comment: @Steven I tried to make it a little clearer. Basically where I put the I bracket mark is the shim I need to make.  I need to add something to raise a section of glass panel to be flush with the door so the latch can fit.

Comment: When you say raising, do you mean vertically away from the floor, or horizontally away from the glass towards the room? I can't understand how your image matches up with your description.

Comment: It does sound like the issue is not the height but the depth...  I don't think you can "shim" this - the door needs to align with the frame in order to latch and seal  properly - even if you got it to lock, I don't think you'd have a weather-tight seal.

Comment: You are correct, it is depth.  I don't think I'm being clear on the problem.

Comment: The commenters here do not seem to think you are being very clear either.  Perhaps some better pictures from a slightly wider angle so we can put it all together what you want?

Comment: @ShoeMaker I'll see if I can get some better pictures up.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Picture is half assed just like like the install. I reccomend getting pin locks for the top & bottom of that door.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you posted under a carpentry tag. however, my solution would be to find a section of Aluminium Tubing, or tubing profile which fits the "gap" which you describe.

[image]

As  You can see, the example picture is a rectangular profile, which will run the entire height of the door, To fill the specified gap.

Your problem will be to attach said profile to the side of the slider. essentially the best thing would be to drill into the frame and insert pop rivets, however, there will be a glass pane on the other side of the aluminium door frame, so drilling will be difficult.

The profile below will allow you to drill your rivets on the side of the door (ie the narrow face of the sliding profile, then you can drill two holes on the top and bottom of the slider (in your photo its the side you can see.

You will then be able to mount your lock flush to the hinge door.

[image]

Above you can see what I mean. I must stress here, that you dont want to break the glass pane by drilling into the frame where there is glass.